# Can I mix a SRAM Crankset with everything else Shimano? (Derailleurs, Cassette etc)

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, shimano, crankset, sram

I was wondering if I could swap a Shimano crankset with a SRAM crankset without any problems

I also know about different BBs like Octalink and chainring size differences

Comment: As I know, chainrings have pretty fixed sizes according to number of rear cogs, so all brands will do them reversible.

Comment: I believe the main reason for possible incompatibility is difference in distance between chainrings and matching it to derailleur movement. It can't be that much for same chain width, so I'd do it. That being said, why?

Comment: @ojs most SRAM cranksets look better than Shimano ones haha

Comment: @ojs on the other hand, Shimano derailleurs look better and have shadow plus

Comment: I think what you're trying to ask is "Are SRAM and Shimano cranksets compatible – can I replace a Shimano crankset with an SRAM crankset? Are there any issues I'd run into?" Is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SRAM chain with Shimano cassette and crankset?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7494/sram-chain-with-shimano-cassette-and-crankset)

Comment: @andy256 nope, I'm on about the actual chain rings and crank arms

Comment: @SanchoJr It's not so much the question as it's answers that match your question.

Comment: @andy256 ah ok I'll check

Answer (score 1):

Probably.  It depends on the exact model and specs.  My GF's MTB has SRAM X0 cranks and Truvative chainrings (i.e. SRAM), with Shimano XTR derailleur and Shimano cassette (not sure of the model).  All of this is 10 speed - but I believe that it might not work as well with 11 speed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they share BB standards it will work. if not Wheels Manufacturing makes adapters for many BB types. Shifting will work fine as long as the bottom bracket is installed correctly.